# Acao a cada loop PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma consulta no sql retornando 2399 registros, divido e executo ela por partes, preciso achar uma forma de dividir o loop por igual, pois se eu dividir por 100 exemplo, ele ainda fica sobrando um loop de 99.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 2399; $i++) {

    $promises[] = $client->postAsync("/localize/1002/consultar", ['form_params' => ['cpf' => $fetch[$i]->cpf]]);

    if ($i % 100 == 0) {
        //$pr($promises);
        //unset($promises);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que quer, porque parece que o problema é outra e nem deveria estar fazendo isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma variável auxiliar:

```
$rows = 2399;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {

    $promises[] = $client->postAsync("/localize/1002/consultar", ['form_params' => ['cpf' => $fetch[$i]->cpf]]);

    if ($i % 100 == 0 || $i == $rows) {
        //$pr($promises);
        //unset($promises);
    }
}
```

Assim, colocando um `OR` ( `||` ), sempre no último registro, irá entrar na condição ( `if` ).

Obs: coloquei `<=` na comparação, se não, não iria pegar o último `2399`.